# Django: HttpResponseRedirect doesn't redirect to next page

Tags: django, redirect, django-views, django-authentication

I'm trying to log a user in using django's `auth` framework and then redirect to a new page. Followings are the files related to the the app (named `portal`).


`forms.py`

```
class StudentLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required = True, label = 'Webmail', max_length = 25)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^stud_login/$', views.stud_login, name = 'stud_login'),
    url(r'^stud_logout/$', views.stud_logout, name = 'stud_logout'),
    url(r'^atry/$', views.atry, name = 'atry'),
]
```

`views.py`

```
def stud_login(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)

        # args = {}
        # args['message'] = "Login Successful"
        return HttpResponseRedirect('portal/atry')

    else:

        args = {}
        args['login_failed'] = True
        args['login_tried'] = True
        args['error_message'] = "Wrong credentials"
        args['login_form'] = StudentLoginForm()

        return render(request, 'portal/login.html', args)

else:

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['login_form'] = StudentLoginForm()
    args['login_tried'] = False

    return render(request, 'portal/login.html', args)

@login_required
def atry(request):
    # message = "Login Successful"
    # args['message'] = message
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/portal/atry/')


@login_required
def stud_logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    # args = {}
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/portal/stud_login')
```

`login.html`

```
<p>Login Form</p>
{% if login_tried %}
    {% if login_failed %}
        <p>{{ error_message }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'stud_login' %}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ login_form.as_p}}

    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

The problem I'm facing is when I put the details in login form at `portal/stud_login` and click `Login`, the view redirects the user to `/portal/stud_login/portal/atry`. And this url doesn't match any of the `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`. It should redirect to `/portal/atry`.

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the leading forward slash. You can fix the problem with:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/portal/atry')
```

In your current code, `portal/atry` is relative. It gets added to the login url `/portal/stud_login/`, to make `/portal/stud_login/portal/atry`.

A better approach would be to use [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) and the name of the url pattern, instead of hardcoding the url in your code.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('atry'))
```

This can be simplified further using the [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect('atry')
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `reverse` and `redirect` functions.